# About relation of ip adresses and number of hosts

Tags: ip, subnet

Question is;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A69YX.jpg

I am not sure about the answer but my thinking is that if there are 35 hosts then `2^x=>35 after that i find x is 6`
it means 6 zero we have on subnet. and others are 1.

```
255.255.255.192
```

this is the subnet mask.

and ip adress would be `192.168.1.x`
x can be everything `0-255`. not include 0 and 255 because of broadcast and network id.

Comment: Note that all educational, certification questions and homework are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help]. However, the Q&A linked above can answer your question.

Comment: Specifically, you seem to be making the mistake that many people do about thinking that the octets actually mean something, but they do not. This is addressed in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) to the above-linked question.

Comment: thank you so much to you both.
it is so subtle point. I understand it.